# Twitter-Bootstrap navigation don't work in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I wan't to use Bootstrap Navigation in Wordpress.
I put bootstrap into the File *functions.php*. 
But the navigation even did not work (in header.php)?

This is where I want to add bootstrap:

```
<!-- site navigation menu-->
        <nav class="nav nav-pills site-nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
        </nav><!-- site navigation menu-->
```

Comment: We need to see more code to help you. Have you made sure that your bootstrap.min.css & your bootstrap.min.js are added in your project?

Comment: Use brief and clear headings, don't put to much into the headline.
You're posted code don't show anything about function.php or header.php. Be aware to describe all needed informations to make people able to help you. 
Add more Background-Information about. You fully missed to explain, that you talk about wordpress. How could other people know this?!?

Answer (score 0):

brother you have to import bootstrap css in the style.css and it works fine in the template or for function.php

```
 function theme_styles() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() .    '/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');

function theme_js() {

```
global $wp_scripts;

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js');
```

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend wp-bootstrap-navwalker:

> A custom WordPress nav walker class to fully implement the Twitter
>   Bootstrap 3.0+ navigation style in a custom theme using the WordPress
>   built in menu manager.

Check out the documentation:

https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker